How can I save an entire TableView to an image in QML
How can I save an entire TableView to an image in QML? I created a basic TableView object tableView. The model of tableView is a C++ instance, and the delegate is a custom QML object. Due to too much data, tableView can only display a part of the items in the parent window, and some items need to be scrolled to see.
If I use grabToImage directly, I can only save the displayed part, and the rest cannot be displayed.

You can either increase the size of the TableView so that it can show all of the data (which might be very slow), or use the positionViewAt* functions to position the view in a loop and stitch together an image that way.

Is this for printing? If so, perhaps you could write your underlying data straight to a PDF or similar?
